# Unable to add Kotlin Serialization to Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin

I am unable to import Kotlin serialization, I think I have followed the instructions from the Kotlin docs but when I use the `@Serializable` annotation I get the following warning:

kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this annotation would not be processed. Make sure that you've setup your buildscript correctly and re-import project.

Here is my project level build.gradle:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.5.5'
        kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
}
```

I created a new module cannotimportserialization just for sanity check and here is the module level (cannotimportserialization) build.gradle file

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.cannotimportserialization'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cannotimportserialization"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2"
}
```

Here is the project level settings.gradle:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Test Project"
include ':app'
include ':cannotimportserialization'
```

[image: warning]

What do I do here to apply the compiler plugin to the module?

Comment: You have two modules, `:app` and `:cannotimportserialization`. Have you applied plugin in the correct module? You might want to [edit] the question to include `build.gradle` files for both modules

Comment: @SergeiKozelko the app module's build.gradle is identical except for the namespace and applicationId. It gives me the same warning in both the modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on the response from the developers in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/2508#issuecomment-1845445564), it's a problem with Kotlin plugin for Android Studio.
As I understand, this problem will be present if the plugin version looks like this: `231-1.9.10-release-459-AS9392.1.2311.11076708` (`1.9.10` is the key part). You can check it in `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin`.

Solutions (from the same response):

> To fix this problem, you need to update the Kotlin IDE plugin.
> Unfortunately, 1.9.20 IDE plugin version is not available for Hedgehog
> 2023.1.1 yet. There are two ways to fix it:
>
> - Go to Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin or invoke action Configure Kotlin plugin updates. Select EAP channel in the window and
>   update to 1.9.20-RC2 (per
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-10755/HMPP-IDE-False-PLUGINISNOTENABLED-in-IDE-for-kotlinx-serialization-plugin-however-project-builds-correctly#focus=Comments-27-8389206.0-0)
> - Update to Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 Canary or Intellij IDEA 2023.3 that have Kotlin 1.9.20 pre-installed.

Comment: This was it, I selected the EAP channel and now it seems to be working.